# Swift round function. Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'

Tags: swift, int, rounding

I'm having a strange problem.. I tried calling the round function in one of my view controllers.

```
let roundedValue = round( letterAmount[ index ] * 10 ) / 10
```

It worked fine.. When i tried using round in another view controller with the same line.

```
let roundedValue = round( letterAmount[ index ] * 10 ) / 10
```

I get the error Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'.

I also tried doing a simple line

```
round( 1.2 )
```

The same thing happens, in one view controller i get no error but in the other i get the error Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'.. Why is this happening?

Comment: what language is that?

Comment: oh its Swift language.. I forgot to include that.

Comment: ⌘-click on `round` and look up the declaration. `Int` and a floating point type are not interchangeable in Swift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Name collision. My guess is that your second view controller has a property named `round` with type of `Int`. Add a namespace to clarify it:

```
let roundedValue = Darwin.round( letterAmount[ index ] * 10 ) / 10
```

Comment: ... or rename your property if you can.